# window.close not working on ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, popup

I'm using Facebook connect on my website and use a pop-up for the login process. Once completed, I have Facebook redirect users to login.php on my website where I update the database. Once done, the script echoes this:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
          window.close();
          window.opener.location.reload();
      </script>";
```

This works fine on every other platform/device but the ipad. I've tried looking for a solution but have had no luck.

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

window.close() doesn't work on iOS after window.open()ing or target="_blank"? do setTimeout(window.close, timeout); where timeout > 300.

[Source](https://twitter.com/#!/gryzzly/statuses/177061204114685952)

Comment: Okay, I'll try that out. What about the window.opener.location.reload() ?

Comment: That should work. You can also try window.opener.location = window.opener.location;

Answer (score 0):

Going into a page via Facebook will cause window.close() nor to work. The only way out is to also provide a window.history.back().
Depending on the situation, users will be able to close out the window clicking on one of those 2 javascript links.